# Nodejs Angular2 and sockets anormal behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, socket.io, angular

I have a small app which use Nodejs, Angular 2 and socket.io. I have a controller who get an array of objects through socket on connection :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: '/templates/public.html'
})

export class AppComponent 
{
    public photos: Object[];
    socket = null;

    constructor(){
        var t = this;
        this.socket = io('/public');
        this.socket.on('gallery-listing', function(data) {
            t.photos = data; console.log(data);
        }.bind(this))
    }
}
```

The server code who send the datas

```
// Sort picture by time
pictures.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.time - a.time;
});

// Emit the result to the socket
socket.emit('gallery-listing', pictures);
```

I precise that the objects give pictures details and contain four keys

So here is the issue : when I test my app with 15 pictures everything is fine. But I tried with 249 pictures and my socket.on('gallery-listing') event listener is triggered 124 time : the first time with an array of 125 objects, then each time it's called again the array length increase. The 2nd call get an array of 126 object, the 3rd an array of 127 objects... Until the last, the 249th which contain an array of 249 objects as you can see on the picture of the chrome dev tool :

[image: The chrome dev tool]

All the console are generated by the console.log in my

```
this.socket.on('gallery-listing', callback)
```

Which is, of course, supposed to happen once. So basically, there is a waste of performance and brandwidth since it load and set into an array like 20000 objects instead of 249. What is the cause ?

Comment: are you saying that with 15 images it runs only once while with 249 it runs all these times? have you tried intermediate cases? It would probably help to see how the array is filled/generated

Comment: @valepu Yes with less than 125 pictures it run only once, and above there is one call more for each with the full array in data each time. What is intermediate cases ? I precise that I bearly start to learn node, angular, typescript and sockets, so total newbie here.

Comment: Sorry i have probably used the wrong term here, i meant to test with values between 15 and 249, nothing too technical. You just said that with less than 125 pictures it runs only once so that's what i wanted to know. How is the array generated/populated?

Comment: ok maybe rather than the array generation it would be more useful to see where your my-app component is used in the html and its template

Comment: @valepu I use jade so I have a layout and a content block. Hold on i give you the code

Comment: @valepu I put the jade layout, the jade content block and the angular template here http://pastebin.com/ziR5ycFu